# mason how to call outside WEB API

Tags: perl, mason

I am using mason to call an API(web based, I can use GET to call it) so that a json file can be returned.

I know `m->comp()` can be used inside. But what function can be used externally?

Comment: What language are you talking about? PERL?

Comment: Almost,it's using perl in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to make an http request to an external url. Since you're just embedding perl in html you could just have a perl block that uses [HTTP::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request.pm) and [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) to make that request. Something like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->request( HTTP::Request->new( "GET", "http://https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=aplusk" ) );
my $data = $response->content();
```

Then have [HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/HTML-Mason-1.51/lib/HTML/Mason.pm) do whatever you want it to do with the json `$data`